# C# Console Executing

Tags: c#, java, jar, console

i would like to have help with this.

Lets say that i want to launch a .jar file trough a bat, like

java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar nogui

Like that.

When i press the bat, It would load in the bat file.
But lets say, that i want to create a console application that when a user presses a button, the console launches the java arg inside the console.

Please help, if you dont understand then i explain more..
Sorry for bad english

~~ redpois0n

Comment: A "console application" with a button? o_O

Comment: "console application that when a user presses a button"... either it's a console app or it isn't. Console apps don't have buttons.

Answer (score 2):

look here for starting a process from c#:

http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx

just create a instance from Process and give it the name of your application and all parameters and then call start

just use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace csharp_station.howto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Demonstrates how to start another program from C#
    /// </summary>
    class ProcessStart
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process java = new Process();

            java.StartInfo.FileName   = "java";
            java.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar nogui";

            java.Start();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: like in my edit above, but your exe must be in the same directory like your jar

Comment: or just Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(PATHTOJARHERE); :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice command line helper that might help you out. You can use this in your console application to launch your process.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/CommandLineHelper.aspx

Comment: It catches an exception after the process closes.
But i can see that it finds everything thats going on in that bat file :D
But i need it LIVE, not after process closes